# isql "select ... where 'a part of a column value' = 'a part of a column value'

Tags: where-clause, informix, isql

I have 2 csv files. In one file I have a phone number with prices and in the second file I have a phone number with the name of its owner.

**First file: file1.csv**

> 491732234332;30,99
>   491723427343;12,59
>   491732097232;33,31

**Second file: file2.csv**

> 01732/234332;Ben Jefferson
>   01723/427343;Jon Doe
>   01732/097232;Benjamin Franklin

My problem is, that the phone number columns are formatted differently and I can not find a way to compare them.

**Desired output is:**

> 01732/234332;30,99;Ben Jefferson
>   01723/427343;12,59;Jon Doe
>   01732/097232;33,31;Benjamin Franklin

My sql statement is

```
create temp table FILETB1
      (phonenr    char(30),
       price      char(30)
      );

create temp table FILETB2
      (phonenr char(40),
       owner char(60)   
      );

       load from "file1.csv"
       insert into FILETB1;

       load from "file2.csv"
       insert into FILETB2;

       unload to "output.csv"

       select FILETB1.phonenr, FILETB1.price, FILETB2.owner
       from FILETB1, FILETB2
       where FILETB1.phonenr = FILETB2.phonenr
```

How do I have to modify my where clause to be able to compare both columns?

We are working on linux with  **IBM INFORMIX-SQL Version 7.50.UC5** which makes finding a working solution not easier since many functions are not supported...

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What OS are you using. I hope is UNIX/Linux if so tell me what shell flavour is in use. Are those prefix (4917? for the csv1 and 0173?/ for csv2) all the same size (5 digits for the csv1 and 5 digits and the '/' for the csv2)? If so, in the csv2 you can use the `tr` command to switch the '/' to a ';' and use `cut` on the csv1 to drop the prefix then you can unload it to a temp table and cross directly the 1st column on the csv1 with the 2nd one of the cvs2.

Comment: The point is not the "tr"! I have problems with the different formating of the phonenumbers. "491732234332" is not the same as "01732/234332" so my "where clause" does not work.

Comment: Note that ISQL is a set of front-end tools; the server version is separate from, and largely independent of, the version of ISQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just the facilities of ISQL, you can use:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE FILETB1
(
    phonenr    CHAR(30),
    price      CHAR(30)
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE FILETB2
(
    phonenr CHAR(40),
    owner CHAR(60)   
);

LOAD FROM "file1.csv" DELIMITER ';' INSERT INTO FILETB1;
LOAD FROM "file2.csv" DELIMITER ';' INSERT INTO FILETB2;

UNLOAD TO "output.csv" DELIMITER ';'
    SELECT FILETB2.phonenr, FILETB1.price, FILETB2.owner
      FROM FILETB1, FILETB2
     WHERE FILETB1.phonenr[3,6] = FILETB2.phonenr[2,5]
       AND FILETB1.phonenr[7,12] = FILETB2.phonenr[7,12];
```

Testing with DB-Access, I got:

```
$ dbaccess stores so-35360310.sql


Database selected.


Temporary table created.


Temporary table created.


3 row(s) loaded.


3 row(s) loaded.


3 row(s) unloaded.


Database closed.

$ cat output.csv
01732/234332;30,99;Ben Jefferson;
01723/427343;12,59;Jon Doe;
01732/097232;33,31;Benjamin Franklin;
$
```

The key is using the built-in substring `[start,end]` operator.  You compare the two parts of the phone numbers that are comparable.  And you select the number from `file2.csv` (table `FILETB2`) because that's the format you wanted.

For the sample data, of course, you could simply use Unix command line tools to do the job, but knowing how to do it inside the DBMS is helpful too.

You could also use the `SUBSTR(col, start, len)` function:

```
UNLOAD TO "output2.csv" DELIMITER ';'
    SELECT FILETB2.phonenr, FILETB1.price, FILETB2.owner
      FROM FILETB1, FILETB2
     WHERE SUBSTR(FILETB1.phonenr, 3, 3) = SUBSTR(FILETB2.phonenr, 2, 3)
       AND SUBSTR(FILETB1.phonenr, 7, 6) = SUBSTR(FILETB2.phonenr, 7, 6);
```

This produces the same output from the sample data.

If ISQL does not recognize the `DELIMITER ';'` clause to the `UNLOAD` (or `LOAD`) pseudo-SQL statements, then you can set the environment variable `DBDELIMITER=';'` before running the script and remove those clauses from the SQL.

Comment: WHERE FILETB1.phonenr[3,6] = FILETB2.phonenr[2,5] worked great! SUBSTR is not recognized as function of my informix version. THX!

Answer (score 0):

The sugestion is, for the **file2.csv** if you use `tr` you get:

```
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ cat file2.csv | tr '/' ';' > file.2
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ cat file.2
01732;234332;Ben Jefferson
01723;427343;Jon Doe
01732;097232;Benjamin Franklin
[infx1210@tardis ~]$
```

For the **file1.csv** if you know that the prefix is always 6 digits long you can use:

```
    [infx1210@tardis ~]$ cut -c7- file1.csv > file.1
    [infx1210@tardis ~]$ cat file.1
    234332;30,99
    427343;12,59
    097232;33,31
    [infx1210@tardis ~]$
```

As you can see you can use the 1st field of the **file.1** to cross directly with the 2nd one on the **file.2**.

Then you can execute:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE filetb1(
    phonenr CHAR(30),
    price   CHAR(30)
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE filetb2(
    prefix  CHAR(30),
    phonenr CHAR(30),
    owner   CHAR(60)   
);

LOAD FROM 'file.1' DELIMITER ';' INSERT INTO filetb1;

LOAD FROM 'file.2' DELIMITER ';' INSERT INTO filetb2;

UNLOAD TO 'output.csv' DELIMITER ';'
SELECT 
    TRIM(f2.prefix )|| '/' || TRIM(f2.phonenr),
    f1.price,
    f2.owner
FROM 
    filetb1 f1, filetb2 f2
WHERE 
    f1.phonenr = f2.phonenr;
```

And you'll get the disered ouput:

```
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ cat output.csv
01732/234332;30,99;Ben Jefferson;
01723/427343;12,59;Jon Doe;
01732/097232;33,31;Benjamin Franklin;
[infx1210@tardis ~]$
```

If you're not sure that the prefix on the **file1.csv** is a 6 digit length leave it and use `LIKE`:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE filetb1(
    phonenr CHAR(30),
    price   CHAR(30)
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE filetb2(
    prefix  CHAR(30),
    phonenr CHAR(30),
    owner   CHAR(60)   
);

LOAD FROM 'file.1' DELIMITER ';' INSERT INTO filetb1;

LOAD FROM 'file.2' DELIMITER ';' INSERT INTO filetb2;

UNLOAD TO 'output.csv' DELIMITER ';'
SELECT 
    TRIM(f2.prefix )|| '/' || TRIM(f2.phonenr),
    f1.price,
    f2.owner
FROM 
    filetb1 f1, filetb2 f2
WHERE 
    f1.phonenr LIKE TRIM(f2.phonenr)||'%';
```